# yeoman angular generator grunt serve not working properly

Tags: ionic-framework, yeoman-generator

when I use the command

> grunt -serve

it gets stuck at this point and not going ahead : [image]

any idea why this must be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happened to me when there was something else running on the port. You can use `netstat` to check what is running on ports in windows; follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) for more on netstat. You will have to kill the process running on that port if it turns out to be the case.

Comment: grunt -serve:compress is working, if that is helpful in anyway. Otherwise I will try your suggestion once

Comment: When you run that command it will likely say something like `Running server: http://localhost:"a port number"` maybe 8100 maybe something else. That may give you a hint as to if 8100 is being blocked. Since compress works I am guessing it is not the code but the port. You could also change the port it is trying to use to something else. To do that look for `gruntfile.js` and use find to get to the part of the file that changes the port.

Comment: ok ya got it ! I had installed Apache HTTP server on that port thats why it was happening. Working now. Thanks !